# Is this the expected behavior of firestore increments inside transactions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

*EDIT: Turns out there is a bug in my code and nothing wrong with the SDK. There is no problem in using two or more atomic increment operations on the same document in the same transaction. For more context read the accepted answer and its comments.*

---

I'm using firestore to count how many users are there in my *users* collection depending on their `childrenSituation` field value. This field can be *HAS_KIDS*, *DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS* or *PERIODICALLY_HAS_KIDS*.

To do so, I have a *data* document in a collection called *aggregated*. This document has three numeric fields which I increase or decrease whenever I create or delete a user by using an atomic increase. But when it comes to updating a user I have to update two numeric values in the same document in the same transaction, which results in setting one of the fields to -1 instead of reducing it in one unit, and not setting the other to any value.

I do this with the `increment` FieldValue like so:

```js
async updateUser(user: User, userChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate: ChildrenSituationEnum): Promise<void> {
    return await this._firestore.runTransaction(async (t) => {
      const userDocSnap = await t.get(this._usersCollection.doc(user.id));
      const aggregatedDataDocSnap = await t.get(this._agregateDataCollection.doc('data'));

      t.set(userDocSnap.ref, this._serializer.serializeUser(user), {merge: true});
      t.update(aggregatedDataDocSnap.ref, {
        [user.childrenSituation]: this._admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        [userChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate]: this._admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
      });
    });
  }
```

I pass the updated user and the previous *childrenSituation* to this method *[I did it to save a read, but I see now that it's unnecessary as I'm fetching the user doc from the DB]*. To update the user, I "serialize" it because Firestore can't take class instances directly and update the document. For the aggregated document, I update both fields using an atomic increase: one is positive and the other is negative.

#### The expected behavior

In my units tests, I create a user in the pretest and so this is the content of the *aggregated/data* document before calling the `updateUser` method:

```js
{
    DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS: 1,
}
```

Then `updateUser` is called and **I expected** the contents of *aggregated/data* to be:

```js
{
    HAS_KIDS: 1,
    DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS: 0
}
```

#### What actually happened

With the same pretest conditions I mentioned, the contents of *aggregated/data* after executing *updateUser* are:

```js
{
    DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS: -1
}
```

Is this the expected behavior for Firestore, or should I open an issue in github? If Firestore is not compatible with having more than one atomic increase in the same write operation, at least it should set it to 0. Right?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "To update the user, I "serialize" it because Firestore can't take class instances directly and update the document"?

Comment: did you mean [user.ChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate] instead of [userChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate] ?

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried to use a `set()` with `{merge: true}` instead of the second update? I have seen too many weird side effects with the firestore FieldValue functions. The `set()` with `{merge: true}` will provide you with the same data result as the update. The only difference is it will create a new document if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec What I mean by that is that if I have in instance of the class User `const user = new User()`, I can't write it directly to firestore like this: `admin.firestore.collection('users').doc('user-id').create(user)` because it throws an error indicating that firestore can't take class instances. So `serializeUser` simply traverses the getters of the class to build a plain js object. It's a sort of buffed `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))`

Comment: @ppicom Ok, I understand. Have you seen the FirestoreDataConverter? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter

Comment: @LeadDreamer no, because this function is meant to decrease one counter and increase another. As the user is already updated when I pass it to the function, I pass the previous value as a second argument. This is wrong and I changed it in the code (not changed it in the answer yet though), as I can read the previous value of `childrenSituation` from the user firestore document that I fetch.

Comment: @Brettski I think I recall trying that. I even tried to set the counter to 10 before executing the update (from the Emulator GUI) and the update still set the field to `-1`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No, I wasn't aware of that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to exactly understand what happens with your code because we cannot reproduce the exact same situation (we only see one function).

However, I've done a test with a simple HTML page, JavaScript and the JS SDK (not TypeScript and not the Admin SDK) and it seems to works correctly:

- Firestore Transaction can execute several writes in one atomic operation, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions);
- If the field does not exists in the `aggregated/data` document it is correctly created with the correct value (i.e. 1 in case of increment on a non-existing field or -1 in case of decrement on a non-existing field).

You can open the following HTML page locally in a browser and test it and find what to potentially change in your code. I've just wrote dummy date to the user doc as I don't really understand what you do with `this._serializer.serializeUser(user)`. You need to adapt the config object to your Firebase project.

Note that you don't need to fetch the docs in order to get their `DocumentReference`: So no need to do `const userDocSnap = await t.get(...)` and then `userDocSnap.ref`. Just do `t.set(this._usersCollection.doc(user.id), this._serializer.serializeUser(user), {merge: true});` since you already know the `DocumentReference` of this doc. Same for `aggregatedDataDocSnap`: no need to fetch the doc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test SO</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        projectId: '......',
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      async function updateUser(user, userChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate) {
        return await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
          t.set(
            db.collection('users').doc(user.id),
            { foo: 'bar' },
            { merge: true }
          );
          t.update(db.collection('aggregated').doc('data'), {
            [user.childrenSituation]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(
              1
            ),
            [userChildrenSituationBeforeUpdate]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(
              -1
            ),
          });
        });
      }

      updateUser({ id: '2', childrenSituation: 'HAS_KIDS' }, 'DOESNT_HAVE_KIDS')
        .then(() => {
          console.log('OK');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer @renaud, I'll try it later to see if it solves the issue. Although, you say that it sets the value to -1. What I'm trying to do is: set a counter that was 1 back to 0, and set a counter that could be nonexistent to 1. If it sets the value to -1 regardless of the previous value you've bumped into the same issue I did. For the moment I've solved it reading the document, updating the values manually and then setting the doc with `merge:true`. Again, I'll try it later! :D

Comment: I was not crystal clear :-) I've updated the answer with "If the field does not exists in the `aggregated/data` document it is correctly created with the correct value (**i.e. 1 in case of increment on a non-existing field or -1 in case of decrement on a non-existing field)**." In other words it works correctly in all cases.

Comment: Hi @ppicom, did you have the time to look at the answer?

Comment: Hi @Renaud! I've tried your solution, and it does work. But the behavior of the admin SDK does not seem to be the same as the client's. Indeed, what I want to do is to use two atomic increments on the same document in the same write operation, and I'm realising now that my question is not well formed. I'm working on simplifying my question and build a simple use case to clearly see the differences in both behaviors.

Comment: I have now effectively confirmed that both admin SDK and client SDK behave the same way. There must certainly be some bug in my code. I'm marking the answer as correct, thank you @Renaud Tarnec